# Why is so much RAM used by the OS?

Tags: ram, process, memory-usage

I executed the `free -m` command and got the following output:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7842       2443       5398        205        167       1631
-/+ buffers/cache:        645       7197
Swap:         8048          0       8048
```

It says that I'm currently using 2443 mb of ram.

After that I executed the following command, which lists processes that use the most memory:

```
ps aux --sort=-%mem | awk 'NR<=10{print $0}'
```

and got this output:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      1346  3.6  2.0 623124 162464 tty7    Ssl+ 22:46   0:17 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
ionut     2810  2.8  1.2 1005224 98508 ?       Ssl  22:46   0:13 compiz
ionut     3232  0.0  0.6 879364 50680 ?        Sl   22:46   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory
mysql     6267  2.6  0.6 550068 48648 ?        Ssl  22:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
ionut     3115  0.1  0.5 1358024 46932 ?       Sl   22:46   0:00 nautilus -n
root      4351  0.3  0.5 526508 46888 ?        Ssl  22:46   0:01 /usr/bin/dockerd --raw-logs
ionut     3084  0.0  0.5 614568 42808 ?        Sl   22:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/indicator-stickynotes
ionut     2801  0.0  0.4 646080 35132 ?        Ssl  22:46   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service
ionut     4761  1.4  0.3 616304 31388 ?        Sl   22:47   0:06 gnome-terminal
```

The ram used by these processes doesn't seem to add up to the used ram displayed in the `free -m` output.

Comment: Your actual memory usage is 645 MB. 167 + 1631 are used by Kernel for buffers and caches to speed up the disk access. The moment any program needs more memory but there is no more left, Kernel releases some from Cache and Buffers, so you can treat  Caches+Buffers as a free memory (not used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine, you're just looking at the wrong values.

Your applications "really use" only 645 MB RAM (-/+ b/c: used) and 7197 MB (-/+ b/c: free) are still available for applications.

The 2443 MB (Mem: used) is the total amount of RAM that your system is using, but including e.g. disk caches and other things which can immediately be dropped in favour of applications, if needed. These kinds of caches speed things like disk access up without having an impact on how much RAM is available for your applications.

On the other hand, those 5398 MB (Mem: free) are truly unused. One could also even say they're currently useless.

More info can also be found at https://www.linuxatemyram.com/